# How to find a set of words in a string?

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on an java and MySQL based application and i have task  to find set of words in a string. no matter what is position of words in a string but should be present in a string.

consider an example: 
  string is  "sector 10 , Delhi" 
  but I am trying to search by Delhi sector 10  
or by sector-10 Delhi   or sector 10 , Delhi

help me to find  such type patter in string by java or MySQL query.

Comment: You can use a Regular Expression

Comment: @MadushanPerera . i have split the string and then find each word in a string by mysql query

Answer (score 0):

must be use FullText feature of mysql :
    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

 for example :
    SELECT address FROM area WHERE MATCH(adrress) AGAINST ('+dehli -bombi' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this

```
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(Delhi|sector|10 )\\b");
       Matcher m = p.matcher("sector 10 , Delhi");
        m.find();
       System.out.println(m.group());
```